# An existing directory is not mounted with newly created LV in LVM Partition

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel7, rhel6, lvm

Suppose there was a LV called **lv_dbbackup** under **vg_root** which is mounted under **/db_backup**. But recently for official purpose I created a new VG called **vg_backup** and by unmounting **/db_backup** from previously created **vg_root-lv_backup** i want to use /db_backup to newly created **vg_backup-lv_backup**. But the problem occurred when i **unmounted** /db_backup from existing **vg_root-lv_backup** and try to mount /db_backup with newly created **vg_backup-lv_backup**. In that case /db_backup is not mounted with newly created **vg_backup-lv_backup** but when i create another directory for example: /test and try to mount **vg_backup-lv_backup** with newly created directory(/test or whatever except /db_backup) it works properly.

I'm using ext4 file system and Its a mission critical system so that i'm unable to change /db_backup mount point cause if i change, then it will be a nightmare to Database Team.

Comment: Hello, after reading your message I do not understand what problem you have, can you rephrase the question, please?

Comment: Please check now. Hope you will understand the problematic scenario than before.

Comment: can you unmount the volume and then execute: "df -k /db_backup" and "mount |grep /db_backup", please?

Comment: To get rid of this kind of problem immediately i make a directory called /db_backups and create a soft link "ln -s /db_backups /db_backup" Purpose solved but its not the solution. I'll definitely try to execute your guideline and let you know.